# InApp purchases produce wrong SKPaymentTransaction state

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

According to the above code section I tried to purchase a product but some times it immediately comes to the following method

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
```

without prompting window for user iTunes credentials and it returns wrong `SKPaymentTransaction` state as `.purchased`.

Hard to find the issue here since it is a random issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a scenario where:

1. You have a bunch of unfinished transactions on the payment queue, so the `updatedTransactions` delegate is actually being hit with purchases you've previously made. If this is the case, you should make sure you're calling `finishTransaction(_:)` for every transaction that comes through the queue (after you've done any required processing on your end). The guide from Apple here has more detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506003-finishtransaction.
2. The transactions you're seeing on `updatedTransactions` are actually renewals coming through from previous purchases. Remember, `updatedTransactions` can be called at any time.

In either case, I would expect that *eventually* the purchase prompt should show. Things could be really slow and bogged down if #1 above is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Don't rely on the Status Notifications**[image]

you have below step for verification

1. fetch Product info
2. make purchase
3. validate reciept
4. update state

if you want to check more please refer below blog :

https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f